# When using the $1-$9 regular expression form, why does calling gsub(...) on one nil the others?

Tags: ruby

First, a working example:

```
string = "foo-bar-25-baz"
if string =~ /(.+)-(10|25)(?:-(baz))?/
  puts $1 
  puts $2
  puts $3
end
```

This produces 'foo-bar', '25' and 'baz' on three lines, as expected. But if we do this:

```
string = "foo-bar-25-baz"
if string =~ /(.+)-(10|25)(?:-(baz))?/
  puts $1.gsub('-', ' ') # Here be the problem
  puts $2 # nil
  puts $3 # nil
end
```

the values of `$2` and `$3` are now nil. I have to `puts $2` and `puts $3` and *then* `$1.gsub(...)`, and it will work. As far as I can tell this only applies to `gsub` and `gsub!`

This causes the same problem:

```
string = "foo-bar-25-baz"
if string =~ /(.+)-(10|25)(?:-(baz))?/
  puts $3.gsub('hard', 'h')
  puts $1 # nil
  puts $2 # nil
end
```

I spent about 15 minutes debugging this and I'm wondering why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gsub` is most likely re-assigning those variables (as would pretty much any other function that uses the regexp engine).  If you need to call `gsub` before using all your original match results, store them to a local variable first with something like `match_results = [$1, $2, $3]`.

Comment: +1, gsub uses a regular expression to find the string to replacae, and so the special variables `$1`, `$2`, etc. will be reassigned!

Comment: Since variables with names starting with a `$` are globals, you never know what else might be able to change their values.

Comment: You're exactly right, it's re-assigning the global variables, which makes sense. Thanks!